# Encrypt password in postgres jsonb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, security, encryption

At my company we're designing a new flow for our user to register. `User` and `Company` are very closely tied to each other. Due to several reasons we can't create the `user` and the `company` one after the other but we need to create them at the same time.

However as our form is on several steps, we collect all the user input in a separate `Registration` model in a jsonb attribute and then create the `user` and `company` at the end of the process from this intermediate model.

One of the problem is that we collect the user password. However as we're storing the `registration` in our database, the password is exposed.

How would you try to protect this?

EDIT: We're using Bcrypt to encrypt password

Comment: are you using bcrypt to encrypt password?

Comment: Hi @Sajin, yes we are.

Answer (score 1):

I have not tried this but I guess this will work. You can use the following code to encrypt the password before storing it as intermediate json.

```
my_password = BCrypt::Password.create("my password")
```

If you have designed the User model properly, there will be a password_digest field in your table. So while saving encrypted password, use:

```
@user.password_digest = my_password
```

instead of

```
@user.password = my_password
```

where you expect encryption to take place in the background.